# CollectionViewCell drop shadow with rounded corners

Tags: swift, uikit

I've `collectionViewCell` and want to drop shadow to it, also want to have rounded corners, but it seems impossibile, cause to drop shadow `clipToBounds` must be set to false, with that, I can't add rounded corners, is there any kind of a "hack" to achieve my target?

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let countryCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MySubscribitionsCollectionViewCell
        countryCell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        countryCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        countryCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        countryCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        countryCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        countryCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 4.0)
        countryCell.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        countryCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        countryCell.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another view to cast the shadow

Something like that

```
let shadowView = UIView()
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        // SET SHADOW
        
let mainView = UIView()
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = true

shadowView.addSubview(mainView)
```

In the case of a cell, you can set the shadow on the cell itself, and set the rounding of the corners and your custom views on the contentView of collectionViewCell